# SqlDataAdapter -- prevent SQL injection on table name?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I have the following code:

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 0 * FROM [tableName]", conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adapter.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Mapped);
```

I am using this to build a `DataTable` of the table schema.

Normally, when people are asking about SQL injection, they are talking about query params :), my question is about the table name:

```
SELECT TOP 0 * 
FROM [tableName]
```

`[tableName]` is actually going to be dynamic / determined at runtime (this is for a framework btw)...

The `tableName` passed into the method is not trusted, so I want to make sure there isn't any funny business going on?

Do I have to manually scrub the table name (and I'm sure I'll miss something)? Or is there a built in method for that? Or somehow to prevent the SQL injection on the table name?

Comment: Get the list of the valid table names and check your input against the trusted list

Comment: I would be pretty wary of a framework that is designed to return data from any table. This is a pretty good indication you are planning on using select * to make everything generic. While this seems cool it comes at a cost. That cost is performance. You can't tune queries like that.

Comment: If you are determined to go with the dynamic sql route like this you should wrap the tableName in QuoteName.

Comment: I am not sure that creating a framework like this is a good idea, no when there are so many already well thought out ORM solutions out there. What actual benefit would this even have? At some point you want to translate/map the columns back to c# (properties or collections for joins) so the caller will have to write code for this probably from ADO. So this is error prone, probably you will have issues with query tuning, and once you make use of it its probably more work than you imagine it will be.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm not returning data from any table. Didn't you see the "TOP 0"? :) I'm just trying to get the schema of the table.

Comment: If you want the schema why not query sys.columns where object_id = object_id([YourTableName])? This provides better information than just a result set. You can determine nullability, defaults etc that you can't get from select *.

Comment: @SeanLange, the end goal was to get a DataTable built from the schema so I can do a bulk insert. The FillSchema method actually determines data types, nulls, uniques, etc :).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query to get a list of all tables in the database and use that as a white list:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM <DATABASE_NAME>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

Replace

```
<DATABASE_NAME>
```

with your database name.

If someone attempts to input a table name which is not in that list, then don't execute the query.

**Update**

As for the "multiple connection strings" case, you can also use a simple query to check the current database name:

```
SELECT db_name()
```

So you should be able to easily craft a method that simply gets a list of valid table names from the current database, no matter if the connection-string/db-name is dynamic or not.  And in the grand scheme of things, I doubt that these two queries are going to affect the performance of your application, like you said, you could easily cache the table list, if necessary.

Comment: Hmm... not sure I want to go that route... the connection string and table name is generated dynamically through templates, so its possible I could have multiple connection strings, table names, etc. Also, this is going to be a high traffic method, so I don't want to do anything super expensive. I could cache the table list, but like I said, can have multiple databases, tables, connection strings, etc. I'd be OK with throwing an exception if the table name is invalid, just don't want to allow somebody to sneak injection in there.

Comment: Do you have any measure that FillSchema is less expensive than a search on the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @PARAMETER ?

Comment: @SledgeHammer - Valid point, just updated my answer a little bit :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could just go with the rules for valid table names

128 char - letters, numbers, and limited other special characters

In those rules I don't think you could do an injection

[CreateTable see table_name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)
[ValidIdentifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

> The tableName passed into the method is not trusted, so I want to make
>   sure there isn't any funny business going on?

One method is to first execute a parameterized query, passing the table name as a parameter (nvarchar max length 128) to the `QUOTENAME` function:

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(@TableName) AS ScrubbedTableName;
```

The returned value can then be used in your TableAdapter query without the risk of SQL injection.  However, this will not prevent disclosure of meta data if a table other than one expected is specified.

Answer (score -2):

You can keep sqlDataAdapter and use

Adapter.selectcommand.parameters.add(@"whatever", value)

Edit: Sorry! I missed the part about this being related to a table name, this code doesnt work. :( I apologize.

Comment: Are you sure you can use the table name as a parameter?